# Only one image from 5 is downloaded and it knocks out an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

url_shoes_for_choice = [
    "https://content.adidas.co.in/static/Product-CM7531/Unisex_OUTDOOR_SANDALS_CM7531_1.jpg",
    "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/1374/2161/products/product-image-897958210_640x.jpg?v=1571713841",
    "https://cdn.chamaripashoes.com/media/catalog/product/cache/9/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/_/1_8_3.jpg",
    "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1EyKjaI_vK1Rjy0Foq6xIxVXah.jpg_q50.jpg",
    "https://www.converse.com/dw/image/v2/BCZC_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-cnv-master-catalog/default/dwb9eb8c43/images/a_107/167708C_A_107X1.jpg"
]

def img():
    for url in url_shoes_for_choice:
        image = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
        out = Image.open(image)
        out.save('image/image.jpg', 'jpg')

if __name__=="__main__":
    img()
```

Error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fa185c52d58>
```

Comment: The error likely happens on the line `Image.open(image)`. Can you open the image with some image viewer? It's actually a `.webp` and not `.jpg` I think.

Comment: You (at least try to) save every image to the same file.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't realize that the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp) only talk about *animated* webp images.

Comment: @lucidbrot: I think all the images are `.jpg`, you can tell by looking at the end of each link.

Comment: @Saad the ending is `jpg` but the file at that url is actually `webp` as you can see e.g. when you try to save it in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one of the images is making issues with the byte data returned by the `requests.get(url, stream=True).raw`, I'm not sure but I guess the data of the 3rd image is invalid byte data so instead of getting the raw data we can just fetch the content and then by using `BytesIO` we can fix the byte data.

I fixed one more thing from your original code, I added numbering to your images so each can be saved with different name.

```py
from io import BytesIO

def img():
    for count, url in enumerate(url_shoes_for_choice):
        image = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        with BytesIO(image.content) as f:
            with Image.open(f) as out:
                # out.show()  # See the images 
                out.save('image/image{}.jpg'.format(count))
```

*(Though this works fine but I'm not sure what was the main issue. If anyone knows exactly what is the issue please comment and explain.)*

Answer (score 0):

I opened the first link in my browser and saved the image. It's actually a `webp` file.

```sh
$ file Unisex_OUTDOOR_SANDALS_CM7531_1.webp
Unisex_OUTDOOR_SANDALS_CM7531_1.webp: RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image, VP8 encoding, 500x500, Scaling: [none]x[none], YUV color, decoders should clamp
```

You explicitly tell the image library that it should expect a `jpg`. When you remove that parameter and let it figure it out on its own using `out.save('image/image.jpg')` the first image successfully downloads for me.

---

The first two images work this way if you make sure to save each under a different name:

```py
def img():
    i = 0
    for url in url_shoes_for_choice:
        i+=1
        image = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
        out = Image.open(image)
        out.save('image{}.jpg'.format(i))
```

the third is a valid jpeg file, as well as the fourth, but using the `JFIF standard 1.01` which I hear the first time of. I'm pretty sure you'll have to figure out support for different such filetypes.

It is worth noting that if I download the images in chrome and open those with python, nothing fails. So chrome might be adding information to the file.

---

The documentation of `PIL`/`pillow` explains [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp) that you need a new enough version for *animated* images, but that is not your problem.

> Support for animated WebP files will only be enabled if the system
>   WebP library is v0.5.0 or later. You can check webp animation support
>   at runtime by calling features.check(“webp_anim”).

Comment: I don't use chrome so I can't say for sure but I think chrome tends to [save downloaded images](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4865645?hl=en) in `.webp` format because I can save all these images in `.jpg` format straight from safari.